# neo4j is using more than 70% of RAM of the Server

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j in my server(16 core) has following resources:
RAM - 32 GB 
heap space - 27GB 
page cache memory -

My graph.db is of 9GB and neostore.schema.db is of 3GB. (i.e 12GB total)
I did the configuration after checking all the performance tuning blogs of neo4j (https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/). Yet the RAM consumptions shoots to 70% or more. I'd like to know the reason for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The size of the database is not relevant to the memory being used. It's what you assign to heap and pagecache that is. So if you have assigned 70% of the server's RAM to the database ... that's what it'll take. If you haven't explicitly assigned memory, a calculation will be used based on the available resources ... and this will always assume that the machine is **dedicated** to Neo4j.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom